# compare the return values of two functions (dynamic quiz)

Tags: javascript

BACKGROUND

I am creating a dynamic, multiple-choice quiz written in JavaScript as a culmination to this [course](http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly). I am following the parasitic inheritance pattern outlined in a follow-up [post](http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know) by the author of the course, and am having trouble completing the project.

PROBLEM

If you refer to this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/merez/3/edit), you will see that I have created functions to loadQuestion, displayQuestion, getUserAnswer, getCorrectAnswer, and checkAnswer. checkAnswer is where I am stuck. In this function id like to check if the returned value of getUserAnswer is equal to the returned value of getCorrectAnswer on the currently loaded question, and if so, just log a string to the console for now.

```
Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function(){
    var questionToDisplay = '<div class="question">' + this.question + '</div><ul>';
    choiceCounter = 0;
    var quizDiv = document.getElementById('quiz');
    this.choices.forEach(function(eachChoice){
        questionToDisplay += '<li><input type="radio" name="choice" value="' + choiceCounter + '">' + eachChoice + '</li>';
        choiceCounter++;
    });
    questionToDisplay += '</ul>';
    quizDiv.innerHTML = questionToDisplay;
};

var i = 0;
Question.prototype.loadQuestion = function(){
    if(i < allQuestions.length){
        var quest = new MultipleChoiceQuestion(allQuestions[i].question, allQuestions[i].choices, allQuestions[i].correctAnswer);
        quest.displayQuestion();
        i++;
        return quest.getCorrectAnswer();
    }
};

Question.prototype.getCorrectAnswer = function() {
    return this.correctAnswer;
};

Question.prototype.getUserAnswer = function(){
    var radio = document.getElementsByName('choice');
    for(var i=0; i < radio.length; i++){
        if(radio[i].checked){
            return radio[i].value;
        }
    }
};

//Non-functioning code, this is what im trying to figure out.

/*Question.prototype.checkAnswer = function(){
    if(Question.prototype.loadQuestion() == Question.prototype.getUserAnswer()){
        console.log('it worked!');
    } else {
        console.log('keep trying!');
    }
};*/

//Load the first question
Question.prototype.loadQuestion();

var button = document.getElementById('next');
button.onclick = function(){
    //get the user-selected radio input.
    Question.prototype.getUserAnswer();

    //Question.prototype.checkAnswer();

    //load next question
    Question.prototype.loadQuestion();
};
```

I am new to javascript (and programming) and suspect that the problem lies in some misunderstanding of how return values work?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please [edit] the relevant code snippets into your post here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

You're not adding 1 to the value of radio[i]. Remember that this is an array, and so all the indices will be decreased by 1 because we start counting from 0.

Here is your function:

```
Question.prototype.getUserAnswer = function(){
    var radio = document.getElementsByName('choice');   
    for(var i=0; i < radio.length; i++){
        if(radio[i].checked){            
            return +(radio[i].value) + 1;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I am using loadQuestion in my comparison because it returns the value of applying .getCorrectAnswer on the currently loaded instance of MultipleChoiceQuestion. My functions work correctly until the checkAnswer function. I think I will edit with more code for better context. Thank you.

Comment: I realized I understood your code wrong. I found the problem and edited my answer. That should do the trick.

Comment: I am incrementing the radio[i].value in the displayQuestion function with choiceCounter = 0; so that if the radio input is checked, then getUserAnswer will return the value of the radio input. This way if the user checks the first radio input it returns 0, second input returns 1, and so on.

Comment: Well, I tried that on my computer using your posted code and it seems to have fixed the problem. It finds the right answer. Might wanna try that and see if it fixes the problem you're talking about.

Comment: I incorporated your edit into the posted [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/merez/4/edit) and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I realize now the problem was more with my approach than any one error. I followed and improved upon an example of another student. Here is the [repo](https://github.com/JoeyBK/quiz) for the project as it stands. The most important thing I've learned is how to encapsulate the variables I need all functions to have access too. In this case, a variable called currentQuestionIndex that increments and is available to all functions was important to the solution.